# Which adjective can be used to describe 'take lots of storage'?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives

I try to use 'storage-consuming', 'storage-expensive', 'space-consuming',  or 'space-expensive'. But I almost found no paper used such words via Google.

Comment: Is *Large* not a good option? You should provide more context

Comment: large storage requirements, including memory and external disk.

Comment: Would your title describe an adjective better if it was "take*S* lots of storage"? Otherwise, it looks like a verbal phrase, and you would be requesting a verb.

Comment: Totally unclear:  Are you talking about something that requires a large physical volume to store (such as 100 bushels of corn), or something that demands a lot of disk storage or RAM storage?

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for `space-intense` or `space-intensive` depending on how you are using it.

E.G.: Space-intensive applications require a significant amount of storage space to run properly.

Similar adjectives could be `memory-intensive` if the application requires significant amounts of RAM/memory; `processor-intensive` if it places high demands on the CPU/GPU; or `resource-intensive` for something that uses something more vague or a combination of several things.

Comment: BTW, what is its antonym?

Comment: I would say something like memory/processor/resource/space-efficient.

Answer (score 2):

It feels like you're after *resource-intensive*, which applies to storage as well as memory and processor utilization.

Answer (score 2):

***Bulky*** - Of large bulk, voluminous; occupying much space (especially with a notion of excess), OED.

Answer (score 2):

**space-hungry** or **resource-hungry**

(sth)-hungry: from meaning of hungry as [wanting something very much](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/hungry_1)

Answer (score 1):

A [memory hog](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/Memory-Hog-Processes.shtml) or [CPU hog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558913(v=vs.85).aspx) take large amounts of resources, often for non-obvious reasons and without consideration for how other applications would need and use the same resources. They can be considered **greedy** in the sense that they make choices about how and when to use those resources based on immediate needs.

The word *greedy* can be taken to mean

> (adjective) wanting or taking all that one can get, with no thought of others' needs ([YourDictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/greedy)).

But the definition goes on with this:

> desiring more than one needs or deserves

So *storage-greedy* might be used to describe an application that takes a lot of storage, possibly more than it needs.

For a young phase, you might also refer to it as a **storage hog**.

On the other hand, it's possible that an application may consume a lot of storage, but it is not being greedy in that sense that it takes more than it needs. In that case, you would probably do well just to say it is a **heavy storage consumer** where *heavy* is

> of great amount, quantity, or size; extremely large; massive ([Dictionary.com #2](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/heavy))

Answer (score 0):

**Sizeable** *(adjective)*

Meaning: fairly large

> Sizeable storage requirements, including memory and external disk.

Answer (score 0):

My photo collection's **voluminous** storage requirements necessitated the purchase of several multi-terabyte hard drives.